# How to use globbing for loop in bash -c command?

Tags: bash, freebsd

I'm trying to run a for loop inside of `bash -c` so I can time it.  This code writes 23 every time.  How can I make it iterate through the numbers?

```
time bash -c "for i in {0..23}; do echo $i & done"
```

This code works, but I need to time the whole operation:

```
for i in {0..23}; do echo $i & done
```

The `echo` command is just for simplicity.  I am really trying to run `dd`, that's why I background the process with &

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues.

```
time bash -c "for i in {0..23}; do echo $i & done"
```

doesn’t work as you expect because `$i` is expanded immediately; you need to use single quotes:

```
time bash -c 'for i in {0..23}; do echo $i & done'
```

To get `time` to wait for all the background jobs, you can use `wait`:

```
time bash -c 'for i in {0..23}; do sleep $i & done; wait'
```

This causes the shell to wait for all its jobs to finish, which results in `time` measuring the time taken for all the operations together.

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense